# Module not loading in AngularJS with Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs, cordova

I have used a scaling platform Yeoman's to build a simple AngularJS app wrapped for Cordova. I am also using Grunt to build the solution before building it for iOS and Android.

My issue keeps coming up when I try to inject a factory that initializes on Device Ready for me to use inAppBrowser.

The error I am getting is:

> Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error

It means my module isn't being loaded, my module is `cordova`.
I have read through the dependency injection on angular and have not had issues with it in the past. So I setup the modules around what is requested by Angular and I'm still getting this error.

My Factory Module looks like this:

```
angular.module('App')
.factory('cordova',['$q', '$window', function ($q, $window) {
var d = $q.defer();
var resolved = false;

var self = this;
this.ready = d.promise;

document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){
  resolved = true;
  d.resolve($window.cordova);
});

//Check event
setTimeout(function(){
  if(!resolved){
    if ($window.cordova) d.resolve($window.cordova);
  }
}, 3000);

return self;
}]);
```

Then there is my App.js File:

```
angular
.module('angularCordovaApp', [
'ngAnimate',
'ngAria',
'ngCookies',
'ngMessages',
'ngResource',
'ngRoute',
'ngSanitize',
'ngTouch'
])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'main'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
});
```

Since I have just built out the application there aren't that many modules yet. The last one is the Main Controller:

```
angular.module('angularCordovaApp')
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'cordova', function($scope, cordova)
{
  cordova.ready.then(function(){
    Notification.alert('Cordova is ready');
    window.location = 'https://staging.hopeelc.com.au/dashboard/';
  });
}]);
```

Index.html to see included scripts:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-aria.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-resource.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-touch.min.js"></script>



<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->

<script>
  angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.cordova) {
      console.log("Running in Cordova, will bootstrap AngularJS once 'deviceready' event fires.");
      document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
        console.log("Deviceready event has fired, bootstrapping AngularJS.");
        angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
      }, false);
    } else {
      console.log("Running in browser, bootstrapping AngularJS now.");
      angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
    }
  });
</script>

    <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/services/cordova.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
```

```
I would simply like to find a solution to why my module is not loading properly.
```

Comment: which version of AngularJS you are using ??

Comment: @AkshayTilekar I am using 1.xx

Comment: is it above 1.6.* ?

Comment: @AkshayTilekar the exact build is 1.6.1

Answer (score 0):

i think problem is due to the missing inclusion of ngRoute module.
Since version 1.1.6 it's a separate part: [Have a look here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute)
try adding and rebuild it

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute']);

Comment: I have that included already i have updated question to show my index.html

Comment: @Keeano add dependency of "ngRoute"